# How to Vertically Flip an BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to Flip an BitmapImage vertically as an a mirror image of the original.
This what I have but it Rotates not flips an image.

```
var tb = new TransformedBitmap();
BitmapImage bi = Type.Image.Clone();
tb.BeginInit();
tb.Source = bi;
var transform = new RotateTransform(180);
tb.Transform = transform;
tb.EndInit();
```

Comment: What type of application do you use? WPF?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use scaleTransform, not Rotate. And set its y scale to -1 to set it as mirror:

```
var transform = new ScaleTransform(1, -1, 0, 0);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348048.aspx

Comment: I needed this vertical flip.
var transform =new ScaleTransform(-1, 1, 0, 0) thanks

Comment: @Taufiq the most widely accepted convention calls flipping the X axis around Y axis a Horizontal Flip.